# How do I view which devices are connected to my AirPort Extreme using AirPort Utility v6.0?

Tags: airport

I recently upgraded to AirPort Utility v6.0, and I can't find where to check what devices are currently connected to my AirPort Extreme. I know that this was possible using older versions of AirPort Utility, and hopefully that feature wasn't removed.

How can I find what devices are connected to my Airport Extreme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click on the AE icon and it will display a list of connected wireless clients.

[image]

Comment: It only shows MAC addresses for some devices here, as far as I can see.

Comment: this only shows wireless clients, which is not what op asked

Comment: Is there any way to monitor the count of devices? My network is pretty close the 50 device limit...